# Can I access the Unity background elements?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, effects

I'm not very familiar with Linux, but have some experience with C and C++. I would like to get in touch with some Visual FX and/or UI development (either C or C++). I was wondering if there is a possibility to access the GUI elements of the Desktop on Ubuntu's [Unity UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29).

What I especially would like to do, is to render animations on the desktop or windows or all over the screen. (particle effects when clicking with the mouse or so).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (Libraries, Documents, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think Desktop Effects have to be designed specific for the corresponding Window Manager.
I think unity uses (some sort of) compiz, so you should look into compiz plugin development.

A lot of "i thinks" so i am not really sure if that'll help you, but good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn a lot more about [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/). There are lot of documentation on line (and some books also). You might code in C++ using GtkMM (but you could consider Qt also). GTK itself is coded in *C*, with well designed coding style and convention. Looking inside its source code is worthwhile.